# Is RegexMatch efficient on large amount of data?

Tags: regex, azure-cosmosdb

I am going through [RegexMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/regexmatch) and trying to understand what will be performance issue on larger records or not, if any.

My goal is to get records where stockNumber is not exact 10 digits.

Example 1 of documents:

```
{
  "id": "abc",
  "stockNumber": "1001234567"
}

{
  "id": "pqr",
  "stockNumber": "200"
}

{
  "id": "xyz",
  "stockNumber": "200111"
}
```

Regex Solution:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    c
WHERE
   NOT RegexMatch(c.stockNumber, "^\\d{10}$")
```

`Request Charge = 6.14 RUs`

Another approach by adding new field:

```
{
  "id": "abc",
  "stockNumber": "1001234567",
  "someFlag": false
}

{
  "id": "pqr",
  "stockNumber": "200",
  "someFlag": true
}

{
  "id": "xyz",
  "stockNumber": "200111",
  "someFlag": true
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    c
WHERE
  c.someFlag = true
```

`Request Charge = 6.1 RUs`

Additional info:

- Now, I don't have large records (let's say 10,000+) where I can see this diff. So would like to understand what is the best approach.
- This payload can have other fields and I can add `WHERE` clause in my query. Not sure how much of diff it will make.
- We have `stockNumber` as a string and this step is to filter out such records.

Comment: Can stock numbers contain non-digits?

Comment: 1) In some regex flavours, `\d` matches a Unicode numeral, which includes more characters than just `[0-9]`, so it can be safer to use the latter. 2) If you know that `stocknumber` only contains the digits 0–9 it would probably be faster the check the length of the string.

Comment: @Bohemian I have seen stock numbers as a string which are invalid. With this action, I am trying to find out such bad records.

Comment: I would definitely expect the simple equality seek to be much better as that can do a seek rather than having to evaluate the regex on every entry in the index (as the `NOT` will likely cause here). But I have no way of proving this on a small collection. The query stats just tell us  "Index hit document count" and not "Index evaluated document count" so doesn't surface any direct stat about additional index entries read that did not result in a hit. I would create a collection with some hundreds of thousands of dummy documents to evaluate this (and look at RU and IndexLookupTime)

Comment: You could look at computed properties here too BTW https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/computed-properties?tabs=dotnet

Comment: @MartinSmith lack of documents are challenge for me too. I'll try to create dummy docs and see how that goes.

Comment: I think the answer here is... benchmarking. Also, 6-7 RU for a query is fairly inexpensive, relatively speaking. And larger documents shouldn't materially impact your query (aside from when you're returning `*` instead of a projection, possibly increasing RU due to payload size, but again... not really something that can be determined without running benchmarks)

Answer (score 1):

Combine your inherently slower regex condition with a simpler and faster condition that the optimizer would likely use first that will cheaply cut down the search space:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE LEN(c.stockNumber) != 10
OR NOT RegexMatch(c.stockNumber, "^e\\d{10}$")
```